# If 'pageinit' executes when a page is initialized, what is the opposite when leaving page?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I need to execute a function when the user leaves the page. This is my code on pageinit. How could I do the same when leaving?

```
$("#page2").on("pageinit", function (myEvent) {

            //Things to do  

    });
```

Comment: Try unload.
https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: `pagecontainerhide` http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-hide https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery's unload event,

https://api.jquery.com/unload/

But it's probably better to use the vanilla javascript beforeunload event as it's probably faster.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload